# XCode:4.6 Lion:10.8 IOS 6.1 error: SBTarget is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

XCode:4.6 Lion:10.8 IOS 6.1 error: SBTarget is invalid , how to solve this?

Comment: I'm with the same problem... Did you already solve?

Comment: Not yet. I use previous version

Comment: Did you check for an extra info.plist file or something similar?

Comment: which item I should check for? The project runs correctly with previous version, but get error when I use the latest one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After hundreds of times testing, I find a way that can help the programme run, 
here is it:

- When you first meet **SBTarget is invalid**, choose `Product --> Clean`
- Run again, this time you may also get error: **SBTarget is invalid**, it doesn't matter.
- Turn off the XCode totally, 'totally' means that the Xcode icon should not appear in the Dock.
- Double click your project file(xxx.xcodeproj , the blue one) to start Xcode, run again. (`Do not Clean this time`), and it runs ok.

Let me know if this can help you or you have any other methods. Thx

Comment: It didn't work for me as described above but I tweaked the step # 3 a bit: my XCode always sits in Dock so I not only exit XCode completely (cmd-Q) but also removed it from Dock (right click -> remove from dock). Make sure you make not of the xcode in question by noting its path before removing from dock (right click on xcode icon on dock -> show in finder). Hope that helps someone else in future!

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue while incorporating the Facebook SDK into my app. The error would alternate between SBTarget is invalid and telling me that my architecture was incompatible with my device so it would not launch. If I followed alexqinbj's advice it would run the app once but then it would go right back to having the same error again. I tried messing with architectures and build settings and removing derived data but in the end it really was just a duplicate file in my file structure. Facebook told me to add their SDK and then to add a folder (that the SDK file already contains). Once I saw that it was just a matter of removing the duplicate file. I've heard of this error happening with duplicate plists as well. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the root cause (in Facebook integration) is the duplicate resources in the Facebook SDK (as per their instructions). When I deleted the resource files (remove references only), this problem went away permanently. Not sure why Facebook instructions ask you to drag the resources bundle over to the Facebook SDK framework you just brought in...

Comment: glad you agree julius!

Answer (score 1):

`TARGETS -> Build Phases`, remove `info.plist` from `Copy Bundle Resources`. Clean and run. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer didn't work for me.  I can provoke this error with 100% certainty.  It is not necessarily an internal consistency issue with XCode that can be resolved through cleaning, rebooting and rebuilding.

SBTarget is Invalid is an internal XCode error.  It happens when attaching a debugger and the architectures specified in the XCode project do not match up with the binary.

On OS X, you can diagnose this by going to the binary on the hard drive and typing:

```
lipo -info <bin>
```

Then comparing this to the build settings ARCH and ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH.   They must match.  It is not enough for ARCH to be a subset of the possible architectures contained within the binary.

There are any number of reasons why they might not match up.  Here are some suggestions:

- You are using an external build scheme.  XCode therefore does not dictate the contents of the binary.  The build settings merely tell XCode what to expect when launching GDB or LLDB.
- The executable specified for launch in the scheme is not correct.  If it can't find the executable, the architectures will not be present.

Answer (score 0):

This error has a very distinct cause in my case. Whenever "Expand Build Settings in Info.plist File" was set to "NO" in Xcode's "Build Settings", this message came up. Will submit rdar to Apple.

[image]